# Is it possible to bind in IB NSColumn NSButtonCell with NSArrayController?

Tags: xcode, core-data, data-binding

I have three NSArrayControllers: one with entities **Glyph**, where each **Glyph** has relationship *to many* to **locations**. Second with objects **Locations** with reverse *to many* relationship **glyphs**, (they are available values for **Glyph.locations**). Third has *ContentSet* set to **Glyphs** *selection.locations*.  Everything works under *MangedObjectContecxt*.

Is it possible to bind NSTableView Columns in some way to add/remove **location** to/from **Glyph.locations** by clicking NSButtonCell in second column?

[image: NSTableView]

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the value of NSButton (checkbox) to show and change a value. If you want something to happen when you click on a NSButton, you have to connect the action.

It is possible to bind the value and observe this value to trigger the action but connecting the action is easier.

Comment: This I now. But is it possible to keep in one column **Locations.names**, but in second one, as <nil> or object relationship to one location from **Glyph.locations** reltionship?

Comment: Do you want to add/remove locations or do you want to show a location depending on buttons in another tableview?

Comment: I want to add/remove relationship **Location.glyphs** <-> **Glyph.locations**

Comment: You can do this in an action method and connect the action of the checkboxes to this method.

Comment: OK, I know how to send action. But how to bind columns? If a first column is bind to **Locations > arrangedObjects > name**, how to bind second one and NSButtonCell?

Comment: If you can't bind the checkbox to a value, you can set the state of the checkbox in the `NSTableViewDelegate` method `-tableView:viewForTableColumn: row:`.

Comment: Yes, I did it this way. Thanks everybody!